# How to manipulate the JSON file in Talend using tmap?

Tags: java

**I have an input file like this:**

```
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "fields": {
    "xyz": "{{xyz}}",
    "pqr": "{{pqr)}}",
    "tuv": "{{tuv)}}",
   }
}
```

**I want an output like this:**

```
{
  /"name/": /"ABC/",
  /"fields/": {
    /"xyz/": /"{{xyz}}/",
    /"pqr/": /"{{pqr)}}/",
    /"tuv/": /"{{tuv)}}/",
   }
}
```

**what i have done in tmap is:**

```
row1.content.toString().replaceAll("\"","\\\"")
```

**But its is not working. 
Please help me to get an expected output.**

Comment: Do you use the return value of `replaceAll()`?

Comment: I just use these components: 

tfileinputraw---(main)--->tmap---(main)--->tfileoutputraw and in tmap

and in tmap i have done this:

row1.content.toString().replaceAll("\"","\\\"")

apart from these things i have not done anything.

Comment: And the return value I am getting from the above tmap code is same as an input provided by me.

Comment: If you want to replace `"` with `/"` in java, then please use `replaceAll("\"","/\"")`.

Comment: Can you confirm that the output is the one you want ? The code is using the wrong slash. If the output is correct, just see my actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row1.content.toString().replace("\"","/\"")` to replace specific character instead of using `String.replaceAll` that use a different logic (with a regex).

You just need to escape the quote to make it work.

With [`String.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) as the javadoc says :

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

So be aware of the behavior it can have.